# jquery show/hide button title

Tags: javascript, jquery, button, toggle, innerhtml

how can I use jquery to get the text inside of a td?

I currently have:

```
<div id="divName">
 <table id="tableName">
  <tr>
   <td id="g${req.Name}</">${req.Name}</td>
   <td><input type="button" id="showName_${req.fName} rel="viewName_${allReq.requestId}
   value="Show " title="Show customer ${req.fName}"
     onclick="buttonToggle(this,'Hide ','Show ','nameDiv_${req.fName}', '${req.fName}')" />
   </td>
   </tr>
  </table>

 <div id="nameDiv_${req.fName}" style="display: none">
  <p>test</p>
 </div>


</div>
```

I would like to be able to have the title of the show/hide button say Show customer John and when the button is clikced to hide for the title to change to Hide customer John and then when the button is clicked again to go back to the title to say show customer John.

I was able to use something like this for the show/hide button:

```
$('ShowHide').click(function(){ 
if ( $('hide').css('display') == 'block' ) 
    $('ShowHide').val("Hide"); 
else 
    $('ShowHide').val("Show"); 
});
```

but how can I get the name to append to show and hide when the button is toggled?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the [text](http://api.jquery.com/text/) method to get the value of your `<td>`:

```
$('#your-td-id').text();
```

[Here's an example](http://jsfiddle.net/3M7ZY/1/) of it working.

Comment: so could I set a var x = $('#your-td-id').text(); and then in the show/hide do something like  $('ShowHide').val("Show" +x);

Comment: @Juan Almonte Yep - that's exactly how you'd do it for your case.